# php include file issue using document root

Tags: php, include

I have used the following code to get the document root.

```
$path = get_file_dir();
function get_file_dir() {
    global $argv;
    return realpath($argv[0]);
}
```

Below code includes config.php and config.php has the $setuprun variable with a value.

```
if((file_exists("$path/admin/config.php"))) {
 include_once "$path/admin/config.php"; 
}
if($setuprun=="true") { 
    //do some code
}
```

In my system, it takes the document root like /home/myname/myfolder and the variable $setuprun has the value and the code works perfectly.

But in another user's system, it shows the following error.

**Notice:  Undefined variable: setuprun in /usr/local/www/chat/setup.php on line 22.**

He is using FreeBSD 8.2 Stable with MySQL 5, PHP5 and Apache 2.2.

Can anyone please help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

define('setuprun', true); //to clear the error

AND this instead setuprun == true..

if(defined('setuprun'))

Comment: Try echo $path; and use debbuger to see what youre dealing with on a system where youre having problem with. Even better remove "if((file_exists("$path/admin/config.php")))" and wait for debbuger to tell you where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined variable means that you didn't define your `setuprun` ... If you define this variable in another document you must check is it included or not before use variables that defined in it.

and try use `dirname(__FILE__)`  rather than $argv[0]

Comment: $path has the value /usr/local/www/chat. Does /usr/local/www/chat/admin/config.php can include config.php or not?

Comment: if your root directory is `user` - Yes !

Comment: $argv variable works only when you run your script from command line